# Is it possible to get the list of SonarQube groovy rules

Tags: groovy, sonarqube

Is it possible to get the list of groovy rules the way we can get java sonar rules via https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search?languages=java webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy Plugin is not installed on SonarCloud. Just install SonarQube locally, install the [Groovy Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-groovy) and navigate to the Rules page of your local instance (and/or obtain *rules* via the WebAPI).

Comment: Is it possible to get the sonar rules for groovy in json format from the local installation with the same information as we get during /api/rules/search call.

Comment: Yup, once the plugin is installed then both the UI and the WebAPI (_api/rules/search_) will return rules accordingly. Editing answer accordingly to be more precise.

Comment: I am able to get the description of sonar rules using following path on the local installation localhost:9000/api/rules/search?languages=grvy. Thanks for your help.